# Getting an error using .on("click") but it works using .click() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I´m trying to use on('click') method.

```
$('.pacotesDesc').on("click",function(){console.log("test")})
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and it doesn´t work.

but when I use .click() method it works:

```
 $('.pacotesDesc').click(function(){console.log("test")})
```

Why I´m getting an error when I use .on("click") method, but it works when I use .click() method in jQuery?

Comment: what jquery version are you using??

Comment: On exists in Jquery 1.7 and up

Comment: old version try ? try `delegate or live` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am assuming if you are using old version of jQuery then according to jQuery; 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

*As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().*

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Otherwise you can elobrate more about your code and i will try to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on("click", ".pacotesDesc", function(){
  alert("Oh noes, you clicked me");
});
```